# Enable paste button only when the clipboard contains text

Tags: vb.net, button, clipboard

I have a textbox and a button called `Paste`.

I want to enable this button only when the clipboard contains text and disable it when it doesn't.

I tried to write this code:

```
If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsText Then
    Button7.Enabled = True
Else : Button7.Enabled = False
End If
```

I'm using vb 2010 and i put this code under all the commands related to `Button7`
but didn't work.

How can I make it work, just when I select text from even any other application and click copy, it goes from
disable to enable without need to restart the program?

Comment: You can try creating another thread, or even put it in a Timer.  `BackgtoundWorker` could also do the trick.  Something that can run that code snippet continuously or in intervals to check periodically and update the Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a procedure every X seconds or milliseconds by using a `Timer` to check if the clipboard contains text.

Something like this

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim CheckClipboard As New CallEveryXSeconds(1000) ' 1000 ms = 1 sec 
    CheckClipboard.Start()

End Sub

End Class


Public Class CallEveryXSeconds

Private WithEvents myTimer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Public Sub New(TickValue As Integer)
    myTimer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    myTimer.Interval = TickValue
End Sub

Public Sub Start()
    myTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Tick() Handles myTimer.Tick
    Procedure()
End Sub

Private Sub Procedure()
    If Clipboard.ContainsText Then
        Form1.Button7.Enabled = True
    Else
        Form1.Button7.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```